# Are there any tools for PMML linting/validation?

Tags: pmml

I've written sections of PMML files on my own and would like to make sure the formatting is correct. Are there any tools that can help with validating the formatting, similar to how there are JSON lint and XML lint tools.

Answer (score 0):

PMML is an XML dialect, so you should be able to use XML lint tools for the job.